# Authorize ADB connection from another connection

Tags: adb, usb-debugging

Let's say that I have access to the phone via serial port (edit: FTDI USB Serial Device converter). I want to install apk, so I need to have working adb connection. But I don't have an access to the touchscreen, to accept authorization dialog. Phone is also connected to the same WiFi networks as my computer. Is there a command in phone shell to accept incomming adb connection?

--edit--

It looks like I don't have enable "Developer options", and what is worse there is no possibilities to activate. Is this blocker issue for authorizae adb connection?

--edit2--

After @Rober suggestions from comments, I have issued activity manager from shell to show developer options `am start -a com.android.settings.APPLICATION_DEVELOPMENT_SETTINGS`, but I'm getting message that it is not available: `Error: Activity not started, unable to resolve Intent`

Comment: What commands can you execute through that UART connection?

Comment: I have access to shell via UART. You mean special command in UART, or shell commands?

Comment: @Robert I have edited question - I'm using "FTDI USB Serial Device converter"

Comment: If you have shell access you can try to send simulated key strokes to navigate and execute something in the Android UI: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8483797/150978

Comment: Sending such input to the device is not problem in this specific case. The problem is, that there is no authorization dialog. Should I have "Developer options" enabled?

Comment: To open developer settings directly: `am start -a com.android.settings.APPLICATION_DEVELOPMENT_SETTINGS`

Comment: Almost done, but I'm gettin info that there is no such activity. Maybe I should look for activity which enables "Development settings"?

Comment: Is this phone locked under some kind of MDM? Those devices usually prevent developer settings from being enabled on production mode.

Comment: I am sorry but I don't think we can help you here. Your device seem to be a non-standard developer board or something similar as it has a serial shell access and no developer option.

Comment: Anyway, thanks for help

Comment: usually developer options is hidden behind build number. for emulating touch events use /system/bin/input. adb can be enabled in default.prop and rsa-key can be placed /data/misc/adb